# Waiting list sign up page redirects without successful sign up

Tags: django, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to get the index page for my beginner's Django app http://chishenma.herokuapp.com/ to allow users to sign up to join a waiting list with their city and email address. I pulled the code for that straight from the register page at http://chishenma.herokuapp.com/register/ (minus a few fields), but even though the register page is working, the sign up on the index page isn't working. For some reason the URL changes to /waiting_list, but no sign up actually occurs (I double-checked in admin, where signs up from the /register page can be found) and there's no error either on the page or in the console. Here's the code for the index and waiting_list views in views.py:

```
def index(request):
    # user_form = UserCreationForm()
    city_form = UserCityForm()
    waitlist_form = WaitlistForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        city_form = UserCityForm(request.POST)
        waitlist_form = WaitlistForm(request.POST)

    if city_form.is_valid() and waitlist_form.is_valid():
        list_item, created = add_to_waitlist(waitlist_form.cleaned_data['email'])

        return redirect(reverse('home'))

    return render(request, "chishenma/index.html", {
        'city_form': city_form,
        'waitlist_form': waitlist_form,
    })

def waiting_list(request):
    return render(request, 'registration/waiting_list.html')
```

Here are the forms from forms.py:

```
class WaitlistForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=35)
    fields = ('user_email,')

class UserCityForm(forms.Form):
    user_city = forms.CharField(max_length=25, required=True)
    fields = ('user_city,')
```

Here is the index.html template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block content %}
<div data-role="page" id="home">

<!-- Header -->
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <h1>Welcome to ChiShenMa!</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="user_area">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <p>Hello, {{user.username}}!</p>
            {% else %}
                <p>We can't wait to show you our app! Please fill in the information below to join our waiting list.</p>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        {% if not authenticated %}
            <form action="{% url 'waiting_list' %}" method="post">
                {{ city_form.as_p }}
                {{ waitlist_form.as_p }}
                <input type="submit" value="Join waiting list"/>
                {% csrf_token %}
                </form>
        {% else %}
        <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
        <!-- Footer -->
        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;" data-tap-toggle="false"> 
        <a href="{% url 'choose_category' %}" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all" style="background-color:#FFCC00; display:block; margin:5px;">Click here to find something to eat!</a>
        </div><!-- /footer --> 
        {% endif %}
```

Here is the waiting_list.html template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block title %}Waiting list{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div data-role="page" id="waiting_list" data-theme="a">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;" data-tap-toggle="false" data-add-back-btn="true">
        <h1>Waiting list</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
  <h1>Thank you for signing up for our waiting list</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

The applicable URL from urls.py:

```
url(r'^$', 'chishenma_app.views.index', name='home'),
url(r'^waiting_list/$', 'chishenma_app.views.waiting_list', name='waiting_list'),
```

The errors in the console when I serve locally:

```
[24/May/2014 16:22:03] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5663
[24/May/2014 16:22:12] "POST /waiting_list/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[24/May/2014 16:22:12] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5663
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I added "data-ajax='false'" to my form, but the same thing happened, except this time in the Terminal I got this:

```
[24/May/2014 16:46:46] "POST /waiting_list/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[24/May/2014 16:46:46] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5681
```

Comment: Well it was a wild guess :)

Comment: so, what are the errors?

Comment: Mihai Zamfir, there aren't any.

Answer (score 0):

This line is probably your problem:

```
<form action="{% url 'waiting_list' %}" method="post">
```

When the form is submitted, the POST is sent to the waiting_list method, which has no POST handling at all (from what you pasted). Instead, all the POST handling is on index.

Try changing it to `<form action="." method="post">` or, to be more specific, `<form action="{% url 'home' %}" method="post">`. Both should sent the POST to `index`, which completes the signup.

Comment: I've tried it both ways, but unfortunately I'm getting "POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/ 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR) jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4"

Comment: That could be just about anything I'm afraid. You should look at your error logs or enable debug mode. I would guess something is wrong in your form handling code, I don't know what `add_to_waitlist` does for instance. The if block that calls `add_to_waitlist` also doesn't seem to be indented enough.

Comment: It is enabled. Unfortunately jQuery seems to swallow the errors. I ended up just getting rid of add_to_waitlist entirely (it is from django-bouncer, which I could never get working all the way).

Comment: You can normally see the error in console (in Safari and Chrome) by clicking on the request. I'm pretty sure that by removing add_to_waitlist means nothing gets saved to database. :)

Comment: Right. I replaced it with the necessary code: new_user = user_form.save()
  Foodie.objects.create(user_wechat=new_user, user_email=user_waitlist_form['user_email'].value(), user_city=user_waitlist_form['user_city'].value())